# When should "self" reference be weak in IOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I just learnt that if you don't make it weak, your viewControllers won't be deallocated(Strong reference). Does that mean every time you close your app, you still leave some "Garbage"(viewControllers) in memory if your did not make it weak? If that is the case, is it true that "weak" should be mandatory for "Self"?

Comment: A good starting point would be https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Comment: When in doubt use the instruments memory leaks tool. It is possible to have retain cycles in objects that should be weak references rather than strong when using ARC. 'weak' is generally used for delegates properties that are referenced in one class, but defined in another class that has it's own logic path for when to be deallocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what self is referring to in your architecture.  If self is referring to a type that needs to be retained in your application then yes it will remain when the app goes to the foreground.  You may want to be sure this is necessary and also make sure you avoid strong retain cycles.